# How can I get this Google Login ID Token from this Android app to verify server-side?

Tags: php, android, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I'm getting the ID Token in my Android app by initiating like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Where `server_client_id` is my SERVER's Oauth Client ID. Then later I request the token with `googleAccount.getIdToken()`

Then on my server (PHP), when I verify the token I verify it like this:

```
$client = new \Google_Client(['client_id' => getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")]);
    try {
        $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($this->idToken);
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
    }
    if($payload){
        $this->verifyPayload($payload);
    } else {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException("Invalid ID Token");
    }
```

Where `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID` is my ANDROID's Oauth Client ID

I'm following this guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating.

On this page it says: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

> When you configure Google Sign-in, call the requestIdToken method and pass it your server's web client ID.

Hence why I'm using the `server_client_id` in my Android app. Is this correct?

> // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend

And this is why I'm using the ANDROID client ID from my server.

Is this right? To be using each other's Oauth client_id's? Or should they both be using the Android CLIENT_ID?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I figured it out. Both the Android app and Webserver need to use the SERVER's key. Even though I created a client ID for the app using it's key SHA1 and everything.

Comment: I don't think your android app should use the server key! Server key should be stored securely. 

Usually this is done like this:
1.request token from the app, with client_id and client public_key. Google will respond with a token.
2.Send the token to server, and from the server (using server key), make another exchange with google, this time you will get a long lived token, the real thing. Store it in database.
3.Use the "real" token to get user information, or whatever you're doing

Answer (score 1):

1. Send authorisation request from the app, using client_id and public key
2. As a response you get a temporary token
3. Send the token to your API. Use it to make another request (from the API to Google), to get a long lived token
4. Store the long-lived token. Use it to request data from google, f.e. user information

Important: never use server key inside the app